# Localize month names - Calendar Railscasts #213

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, calendar

i'm try tutorial calendar from railscasts episode #213.
i have add es.yml but not worked.
i try localize month names with replace word on en.yml such as

```
en:
  date:

    month_names: [~, Enero, Febrero, Marzo, Abril, Mayo, Junio, Julio, Agosto, Septiembre, Octubre, Noviembre, Diciembre]
    abbr_month_names: [~, Ene, Feb, Mar, Abr, May, Jun, Jul, Ago, Sep, Oct, Nov, Dic]
```

not working too

on html.erb

```
<h2 id="month"><%= @date.strftime("%B %Y") %></h2>
```

i want change this

[image]

anyone help me?

thank's

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You should use the `localize` method of I18n (shortened as `l`):

```
<h2 id="month"><%= l(@date) %></h2>
```

Then you can set different formats on your own:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html#adding-date-time-formats

```
# config/locales/es.yml
es:
  date:
    formats:
      short: "%B %Y"
      default: "%D %m, %Y"
```

And use it like this:

```
<h2 id="month"><%= l(@date, format: :short) %></h2>
```

Comment: I18n::ArgumentError in Admin/calendars#index

Showing c:/Sites/edu/app/views/admin/calendars/index.html.erb where line #13 raised:

line 13 <h2 id="month"><%= l(@date.strftime("%B %Y")) %></h2>

Object must be a Date, DateTime or Time object. "December 2012" given.

Comment: The error tells you that you are giving a String, not a Date object. Give the `@date` variable to localize without any `strftime` !

Answer (score 0):

just want to clarify that if you use with active record, just simply convert the string `datetime` value to `date` object as example below.

```
en:
  date:
    formats:
      default: "%Y-%m-%d"
      short: "%b %d"
      long: "%B %d, %Y"
    enter code here
```

`<%= l(post.the_created_at.to_date, format: :long) %>`